# Consulta compleja en Mongo - Geocom (Retail)

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql

Buen dia.

Tengo el siguiente documento **json** de ejemplo.

Se trata de la estructura de un ticket o número de factura de un Retail, correspondiente a una empresa uruguaya del rubro llamada **GEOCOM**.

```
{
    "_id": "5f7c17c0c40a0ca0e9deb18e",
    "T": {
        "HD": {
            "HD01": "1",
            "HD02": "20201006",
            "HD03": "1001",
            "HD04": "4",
            "HD05": 4,
            "HD06": "20201006040539",
            "HD07": "",
            "HD08": "3736803",
            "HD09": "PYG",
            "HD10": "PYG",
            "HD11": "0010470000002",
            "HD12": "",
            "HD13": "",
            "HD14": "",
            "HD15": "",
            "HD16": "",
            "HD17": "",
            "HD18": "",
            "HD19": "",
            "HD20": "",
            "HD21": 46950,
            "HD22": "ICAE",
            "HD23": false,
            "HD24": false,
            "HD26": -34.0,
            "HDEL": {
                "HDE": [{
                        "HDE1": "DATA",
                        "HDE2": "stampedNumber",
                        "HDE3": "14350465"
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "ticketWait",
                        "HDE3": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "ticketRecovery",
                        "HDE3": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "ticketCancel",
                        "HDE3": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "ROUNDED",
                        "HDE3": "-34.0"
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "REASON_CANCELLATION"
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENCNC",
                        "HDE2": "NC_MOTI"
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "VERSION",
                        "HDE3": "100"
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "CASHIER_NAME",
                        "HDE3": "LETICIA MABEL"
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "CASHIER_LAST_NAME",
                        "HDE3": "NOLDIN SARABIA"
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "COUPON_CODES",
                        "HDE3": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "BRANCH_OFFICE",
                        "HDE3": "CASA CENTRAL"
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "ECOMMERCE_SALE",
                        "HDE3": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "ECOMMERCE_ORDER_NUMBER",
                        "HDE3": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "HDE1": "ENC",
                        "HDE2": "ECOMMERCE_ORDER_STATE",
                        "HDE3": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "ID": {
                "ID01": "SIN NOMBRE",
                "ID02": "444444017",
                "ID04": "N/A N/A",
                "ID05": "N/A",
                "ID06": "PARAGUAYAN_RUC"
            }
        },
        "SIEL": {
            "SIE": [{
                    "sequenceNumber": 0,
                    "itemId": "3010",
                    "itemDescription": "COSTELETA VACUNA BAN",
                    "unitAmount": 29950,
                    "quantity": 1.405,
                    "subTotalAmount": 42080,
                    "discountAmount": 0,
                    "totalAmount": 42080,
                    "taxes": {
                        "tax": [{
                            "taxRule": "2",
                            "affectedAmount": 40076,
                            "taxAmount": 2004,
                            "taxRuleRate": "0.05"
                        }]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "sequenceNumber": 1,
                    "itemId": "1010",
                    "itemDescription": "GALLETA CRIOLLA",
                    "unitAmount": 4800,
                    "quantity": 0.605,
                    "subTotalAmount": 2904,
                    "discountAmount": 0,
                    "totalAmount": 2904,
                    "taxes": {
                        "tax": [{
                            "taxRule": "1",
                            "affectedAmount": 2640,
                            "taxAmount": 264,
                            "taxRuleRate": "0.1"
                        }]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "sequenceNumber": 2,
                    "itemId": "4002",
                    "itemDescription": "LECHUGA NACIONAL X M",
                    "unitAmount": 1000,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "subTotalAmount": 2000,
                    "discountAmount": 0,
                    "totalAmount": 2000,
                    "taxes": {
                        "tax": [{
                            "taxRule": "2",
                            "affectedAmount": 1905,
                            "taxAmount": 95,
                            "taxRuleRate": "0.05"
                        }]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "SIL": {
            "SI": [{
                    "SI01": 0,
                    "SI02": "S",
                    "SI03": "2003010014058",
                    "SI04": "2003010014058",
                    "SI05": 1.405,
                    "SI06": "KG",
                    "SI07": 29950,
                    "SI08": 42080,
                    "SI09": "SCAN",
                    "TXL": [{
                        "taxRule": "2",
                        "taxAmount": 2004
                    }],
                    "ESI": [{
                        "name": "grossPrice",
                        "value": "42080"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "SI01": 1,
                    "SI02": "S",
                    "SI03": "2001010006059",
                    "SI04": "2001010006059",
                    "SI05": 0.605,
                    "SI06": "KG",
                    "SI07": 4800,
                    "SI08": 2904,
                    "SI09": "SCAN",
                    "TXL": [{
                        "taxRule": "1",
                        "taxAmount": 264
                    }],
                    "ESI": [{
                        "name": "grossPrice",
                        "value": "2904"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "SI01": 2,
                    "SI02": "S",
                    "SI03": "2404002000026",
                    "SI04": "2404002000026",
                    "SI05": 2.0,
                    "SI06": "UN",
                    "SI07": 1000,
                    "SI08": 2000,
                    "SI09": "SCAN",
                    "TXL": [{
                        "taxRule": "2",
                        "taxAmount": 95
                    }],
                    "ESI": [{
                        "name": "grossPrice",
                        "value": "2000"
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        "DIL": {
            "DI": [

            ]
        },
        "PML": {
            "PM": [{
                "PM01": "1",
                "PM02": 46950,
                "PM03": "PYG",
                "PM04": false,
                "PM05": 46950,
                "PM06": 0,
                "EPM": [{
                        "name": "Payment_Mode_Name",
                        "value": "Efectivo"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "GROUP_Payment_Mode_Name",
                        "value": "DATA"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    },
    "updated": "2020-10-06T07:07:44.433+0000"
}
```

Necesito hacer una consulta en mongo basada en la siguiente premisa:

- La suma de todos los impuestos (**taxes**), agrupados por gravadas 10 e iva 10 (**taxRule:2**), gravadas 5 e iva 5 (**taxRule:1**) y exentas (**taxRule:0**), separados por tipo de documento (Venta y Nota de credito) y en un rango de tiempo especifico.

No estoy seguro de si esta consulta es simple o compleja de obtener. He realizado un curso básico-intermedio de Mongo en **Udemy**. Estoy en esto hace solo una semana. He logrado consultar varias cosas, pero esto parece muy dificil.

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

**Referencia**:

- **T.HD.HD11** corresponde al Número de factura
- **T.HD.HD02** es la fecha
- **T.HD.HD21** es el monto de la factura
- **T.SIEL.SIE** son los detalles de la venta

  - **T.SIEL.SIE.taxes.tax** son los impuestos dentro del detalle
  - **T.SIEL.SIE.taxes.tax.taxRule** es el tipo de impuesto, el cual esta detallado mas arriba
  - **T.SIEL.SIE.taxes.tax.affectedAmount** es el monto de las gravadas
  - **T.SIEL.SIE.taxes.tax.taxAmount** es el monto de las ivas (impuesto al valor agregado, en mi pais)
- **T.SIL.SI.SI02** corresponde al tipo de documento (**S** para **venta**), (**C** para **Nota de credito**)

Añado el codigo **SQL** que utilizo para obtener esta información desde **MariaDB**

```
select t.localid, 
case
    when t.documenttype='sale' then 'Venta' 
    when t.documenttype='return' then 'Nota Credito' end 'Documento',
sum(if(tet.taxid=1,tet.affectedamount,0)) 'Gravada 10',
sum(if(tet.taxid=1,tet.amount,0)) as 'Iva 10',
sum(if(tet.taxid=2,tet.affectedamount,0)) 'Gravada 5', 
sum(if(tet.taxid=2,tet.amount,0)) as 'Iva 5',
sum(if(tet.taxid=0,tet.affectedamount,0)) 'Exenta' from tickets t
inner join ticketentriestaxes tet on
    (t.pos=tet.pos and t.localid=tet.localid and t.opendate=tet.opendate and t.ticketnumber=tet.ticketnumber)
    where date(t.opendate) >= '2021-04-16' and date(t.opendate) <= '2021-04-16' and t.state='D' and tet.taxid in (0,1,2) 
    and t.documenttype in ('sale','return') 
    group by t.documenttype;
```

Con el cual obtengo la informacion de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]